# Immutable JS - Extracting values to array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I have a record from my Redux store that looks like the following

```js
const fruitRecord = Immutable.fromJS({
  '8a6sd5v8a6s7fv5': {id: '1234', fruit: 'banana'},
  'hvth1jk34v23hj2': {id: '5678', fruit: 'apple'}
  });
```

If I console log the record I get

```
console.log(fruitRecord.toArray())
// [Array(2), Array(2)]
// 0: ["8a6sd5v8a6s7fv5", FruitRecord]
// 1: ["hvth1jk34v23hj2", FruitRecord]
```

I am interested in the fruit Ids (`1234` and `5678` in this example) and put them in an array.

Here is what I am trying to do at the moment:

```js
const fruitName = fruitRecord.map(f => {
    console.log(f.get('id')) // prints 1234 and 5678
    return f.get('id')
})

console.log(fruitName)
// returns a Map
```

But the problem is when try to use `fruitIds` I get a type object. I would expect that to be an array `['1234', '5678']`

How can I change my code to get an array of the ids?

** Edit ** changed the example to be reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the array are of type object. for example if you log the type of an array you'll get "object"

Example:

```
const array = [1,2,3],
console.log(typeof array); // this will print object.
```

I think you should try printing out "fruitIds". it will be in the form of an array.

Another approach can be as following.

```
const fruitArray = [];
fruitRecord.map(f => {
    console.log(f.get('id')) // prints 1234 and 5678
    fruitArray.push(f.get('id')); // or frruitArray.push(f.id);
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that. I edited the sample code btw

Comment: You can initialize an array just before the map function. and then push the ids from inside of the map functions.
This can be a good approach.